# Adding items to DataGridViewComboBoxCell in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm using below code with COM interface object.

```
Public Shared Sub ExportPa(ByVal mdl As IScrModel, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Try
        dgv.Rows.Clear()
        If mdl.findElement(My.Settings.str_elem__subvar_grpname_pa, False) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim grpList As IScrSubVarGroup = CType(mdl.findElement(My.Settings.str_elem__subvar_grpname_pa, False), IScrSubVarGroup)
            For i As Integer = 0 To grpList.getSubvarList(True).count - 1
                Dim obj As IScrSubVar = CType(grpList.getSubvarList(True).item(i), IScrSubVar)
                Dim countRow As Integer = dgv.RowCount

                If obj.intent.val = IntentStatusCBO() Then
                    Select Case obj.get_discr_str.Length
                        Case Is > 1
                            dgv.Rows.Add(countRow, obj.fullName.Substring(My.Settings.str_elem__subvar_grpname_pa.Length + 1), "discr")
                            Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
                            cbCell = CType(dgv.Rows(countRow).Cells(3), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                            cbCell.Items.Clear()
                            For iIndex = 0 To UBound(obj.get_discr_desc())
                                cbCell.Items.Add(obj.get_discr_desc().GetValue(iIndex))
                                cbCell.Value = obj.discr_desc(Array.IndexOf(obj.get_discr_str(), obj.str.src)).src
                            Next
                        Case Else
                            dgv.Rows.Add(countRow, obj.fullName.Substring(My.Settings.str_elem__subvar_grpname_pa.Length + 1), "std")
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In the following code i'd like to add received array from object "obj.get_discr_desc()" to my comboboxcell. Each object's array has different arrays so i have to add cell by cell. The code is working good now but i don't know is it the correct way?

```
Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
cbCell = CType(dgv.Rows(countRow).Cells(3), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
cbCell.Items.Clear()
For iIndex = 0 To UBound(obj.get_discr_desc())
    cbCell.Items.Add(obj.get_discr_desc().GetValue(iIndex))
    cbCell.Value = obj.discr_desc(Array.IndexOf(obj.get_discr_str(), obj.str.src)).src
Next
```

Comment: SO is not a place for questions of the form "I want to do X and this code does it, but I want to know if it could be better". There are other places for that sort of things. SO is for when your code doesn't do as you expect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of question does not belong on this site. You might try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).